# Class with same interface in c++ lib and program. Exe version is

Tags: c++, linker, static-libraries

I have a static library which has a class Bar with same interface defined in the header file in c++ lib and program. The exe has slightly different Bar.cpp source code and creates the object with different values. See code below.

Static Library files. (Lib_project\Foo_lib)

Lib_project\foo_lib.h

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int printBarA() const;
};
```

Lib_project\foo_lib.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Foo_lib.h"
#include "Bar.h"

int Foo::printBarA() const
{
    Bar bar;
    std::cout << "bar.getA() : " << bar.getA() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Lib_project\Bar.h

```
// Lib Bar definition
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar();
    int getA() const;
private: 
    int a;
};
```

Lib_project\Bar.cpp

```
#include "Bar.h"

Bar::Bar() : a(99) {}  // Different value here
int Bar::getA() const { return a; }
```

---

Main program exe code (shared_class)

Bar.h

```
// exe Bar definition
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar();
    int getA() const;
private:
    int a;
};
```

bar.cpp

```
#include "Bar.h"

Bar::Bar() : a(66) { }  // Different value here
int Bar::getA() const { return a; }
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Lib_project\Foo_lib.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.printBarA();
    return 0;
}
```

---

Once compiled the output of the program is as below. The Foo_lib method Foo::printBarA() creates the Bar object as defined in the main.exe Bar.cpp with a=66; rather than as defined in the lib Bar.cpp which has a=99;

```
D:\shared_class>Release\shared_class.exe
bar.getA() : 66
```

Compiling as DLL fixed it on windows, but as shared library on linux the problem still occurs, so I need a fix that is platform independent.

So my questions are:

1. Why does this happen? (I'm thinking do to .obj files being discarded
   at link time.)
2. What are my options for stopping this behaviour so that the Bar.cpp from the Foo_lib.lib is used and will print bar.getA() : 99?

   - Wrap all library files in a namespace? Or renaming classes? I have
     a lot of files in the actual case. Are there any linker or compiler
     options than would work?

Thanks

**Resolution:**

I had to wrap every class in a namespace to avoid any conflicts. Everything works as expected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are violating the one definition rule (ODR) by having the same class (`::Bar`) with two slightly differing definitions in the same program. Your program's behavior is completely undefined.

To solve this, you *have* to rename one definition of `Bar`, either by changing the actual name, or putting it in a namespace.

(As for technical details why this happens, it is due to the way linkers use static libraries to resolve dependencies. But since it is UB, you can't rely on it.)